# Sort multi dimensional array by [type]

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, multidimensional-array

how can I sort this array by type like video then Simple Page ?

```
print_r($result);
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [link] => http://localhost/test/test
    [type] => Video
    [title] => Treasurer Robot
    [date] => 1359397195
    [node] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 9
            [type] => video
            [language] => 
            [uid] => 1
            [status] => 1
            [created] => 1344351903
            [changed] => 1359397195
            [comment] => 0
            [promote] => 1
    )
)

Array
(
    [link] => http://localhost/test/test
    [type] => Simple Page
    [title] => Treasurer Robot2
    [date] => 1359397193
    [node] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 11
            [type] => Simple Page
            [language] => 
            [uid] => 1
            [status] => 1
            [created] => 1344351903
            [changed] => 1359397195
            [comment] => 0
            [promote] => 1
    )
)

Array
(
    [link] => http://localhost/test/test
    [type] => Video
    [title] => Treasurer Robot3
    [date] => 1359397195
    [node] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 19
            [type] => video
            [language] => 
            [uid] => 1
            [status] => 1
            [created] => 1344351903
            [changed] => 1359397195
            [comment] => 0
            [promote] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: I would use http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

There are many php sort functions.  Kindly find one which suits you from the below url.
http://resource.gvignesh.org/use-the-power-of-these-php-functions-to-sort-your-arrays/

Comment: I would recommend changing the way you post content on your site, currently it's not very readable (by me at least).

Comment: Okay.  I am working on that and coding my own blog.  Soon it will be replaced.  Sorry for the inconvenience happen..

Answer (score 0):

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}
aasort($your_array,"order");
```